# Generic error handler function for POSIX shell scripts

Tags: error-handling, linux, sh, posix

### Intention

I came with the idea of generic, portable, highly reliable, and further customizable function for Shell scripts, written in [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), for error handling.

### Purpose

The function shall find out, if the terminal has color support, and act accordingly. If it has, then I highlight the *error origin* and the *exit code* with different colors. The main message shall be tabbed from the left, all for the best readability.

### Example function call and error handler output (**textual**) + Explanation

`print_usage_and_exit` is a self-explanatory function, which watches over the number of given arguments, it accepts exactly one, let's give it some more:

**Example function:**

```
print_usage_and_exit()
{
    # check if exactly one argument has been passed
    [ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || print_error_and_exit 1 "print_usage_and_exit" "Exactly one argument has not been passed!\\n\\tPassed: ${*}"

    # check if the argument is a number
    is_number "${1}" || print_error_and_exit 1 "print_usage_and_exit" "The argument is not a number! Exit code expected."

    echo "Usage:   ${0} [-1]"
    echo "         -1: One-time coin collect."
    echo "Default: Repeat coin collecting until interrupted."
    exit "${1}"
}
```

**Example function call - erroneous:**

```
print_usage_and_exit a b c 1 2 3
```

**Example output:**

```
print_usage_and_exit()

        Exactly one argument has not been passed!
        Passed: a b c 1 2 3

exit code = 1
```

### Example error handler output (visual)

[image: Example error handler output (visual)]

### The actual error handler function code

```
print_error_and_exit()
# expected arguments:
# $1 = exit code
# $2 = error origin (usually function name)
# $3 = error message
{
    # check if exactly 3 arguments have been passed
    # if not, print out an internal error without colors
    if [ "${#}" -ne 3 ]
    then
        printf "print_error_and_exit() internal error\\n\\n\\tWrong number of arguments has been passed: %b!\\n\\tExpected the following 3:\\n\\t\\t\$1 - exit code\\n\\t\\t\$2 - error origin\\n\\t\\t\$3 - error message\\n\\nexit code = 1\\n" "${#}" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    # check if the first argument is a number
    # if not, print out an internal error without colors
    if ! [ "${1}" -eq "${1}" ] 2> /dev/null
    then
        printf "print_error_and_exit() internal error\\n\\n\\tThe first argument is not a number: %b!\\n\\tExpected an exit code from the script.\\n\\nexit code = 1\\n" "${1}" 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    # check if we have color support
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        # colors definitions
        readonly bold=$(tput bold)
        readonly red=$(tput setaf 1)
        readonly yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
        readonly nocolor=$(tput sgr0)
        # combinations to reduce the number of printf references
        readonly bold_red="${bold}${red}"
        readonly bold_yellow="${bold}${yellow}"
        # here we do have color support, so we highlight the error origin and the exit code
        printf "%b%b()\\n\\n\\t%b%b%b\\n\\nexit code = %b%b\\n" "${bold_yellow}" "${2}" "${nocolor}" "$3" "${bold_red}" "${1}" "${nocolor}" 1>&2
        exit "$1"
    else
        # here we do not have color support
        printf "%b()\\n\\n\\t%b\\n\\nexit code = %b\\n" "${2}" "${3}" "${1}" 1>&2
        exit "$1"
    fi
}
```

### EDIT

I realized the `tput` could very well be anywhere else than in `/usr/bin/`.

So, while keeping the original code untouched, I have changed the line:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

to a more plausible check:

```
if command -v tput > /dev/null 2>&1 && tput setaf 1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a big fan of `tput`, which many script authors seem to overlook, for generating appropriate terminal escapes.  Perhaps my enthusiasm started back in the early '90s, when using idiosyncratic (non-ANSI) terminals, but it still glows bright whenever I run a command in an Emacs buffer or output to a file.

---

A style point, on which you may disagree: I prefer not to enclose parameter names in braces unless it's required (for transforming the expansion, or to separate from an immediately subsequent word).  So `[ "$#" -ne 3 ]` rather than `[ "${#}" -ne 3 ]`, for example.  The braces aren't *wrong*, but do feel unidiomatic there.

---

A simple improvement: you can save a lot of doubled-backslashes in the `printf` format strings by using single quotes rather than double quotes (this also protects you against accidentally expanding variables into the format string).  I also find it easier to match arguments to format if I make judicious use of line continuation.  Example:

```
    printf '%s%b()\n\n\t%s%b%s\n\nexit code = %b%s\n' \
           "$bold_yellow" "$2" \
           "$nocolor" "$3" "$bold_red" \
           "$1" "$nocolor" >&2
```

---

The definition of `is_number` isn't shown in your example function, but something similar is written in full here:

```
# check if the first argument is a number
# if not, print out an internal error without colors
if ! [ "${1}" -eq "${1}" ] 2> /dev/null
then
```

I think it makes sense to have `is_number` for that test; it would certainly reduce the need for comments:

```
if ! is_number "$1"
then    # print out an internal error without colors
```

---

It probably makes sense to redirect output to the error stream once at the beginning of `print_error_and_exit`, since we won't be generating any ordinary output from this point onwards:

```
print_error_and_exit()
{
    exec >&2
```

That saves the tedium of adding a redirect to every output command, and neatly avoids the easy mistake of missing one.

---

When we test that `tput` succeeds, perhaps we should `tput sgr0` without redirecting to null, so that the output device is in a known state (thus killing two birds with one stone)?

If `tput` works at all, then when its argument can't be converted, its output is empty, which is fine.  If we want to be really robust when `tput` doesn't even exist, then we could test like this:

```
tput sgr0 2>/dev/null || alias tput=true
```

Then we don't need a separate branch for the non-coloured output (we'll just output empty strings in the formatting positions).  That won't quite work as I've written it, unless we specifically export the alias to sub-shells, but we can more conveniently just use a variable:

```
tput=tput
$tput sgr0 2>/dev/null || tput=true
```

We might also choose to test that the output is a tty (`test -t 1`, if we've done the `exec` I suggested, else `test -t 2`).

---

`$bold_yellow` saves no typing compared to `$bold$yellow`, and it's only used once anyway, so it can easily be eliminated.  Same for `$bold$red`.

---

## Modified code

Applying my suggestions, we get:

```
is_number()
{
    test "$1" -eq "$1" 2>/dev/null
}

print_error_and_exit()
# expected arguments:
# $1 = exit code
# $2 = error origin (usually function name)
# $3 = error message
{
    # all output to error stream
    exec >&2

    if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]
    then    # wrong argument count - internal error
        printf 'print_error_and_exit() internal error\n\n\tWrong number of arguments has been passed: %b!\n\tExpected the following 3:\n\t\t\$1 - exit code\n\t\t\$2 - error origin\n\t\t\$3 - error message\n\nexit code = 1\n' \
               "$#"
        exit 1
    fi

    if ! is_number "$1"
    then    # wrong argument type - internal error
        printf 'print_error_and_exit() internal error\n\n\tThe first argument is not a number: %b!\n\tExpected an exit code from the script.\n\nexit code = 1\n' \
               "$1"
        exit 1
    fi

    # if tput doesn't work, then ignore
    tput=tput
    test -t 1 || tput=true
    $tput sgr0 2>/dev/null || tput=true
    
    # colors definitions
    readonly bold=$($tput bold)
    readonly red=$($tput setaf 1)
    readonly yellow=$($tput setaf 3)
    readonly nocolor=$($tput sgr0)

    # highlight the error origin and the exit code
    printf '%s%b()\n\n\t%s%b%s\n\nexit code = %b%s\n' \
           "${bold}$yellow" "$2" \
           "$nocolor" "$3" "${bold}$red" \
           "$1" "$nocolor"

    exit "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I largely re-written the error handling functions. The reasons were multiple. Mostly, I needed greater flexibility, reliability and even a bit more general-purpose use.

---

### File `func-color_support`

First, I created this separate file for defining colors and determining if terminal colors are supported:

```sh
#!/bin/sh


# do not warn that variables appear unused
# this file is being sourced by other scripts
# link to wiki: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2034
# shellcheck disable=SC2034


### REQUIREMENTS
# none


### METHODS
## tput_colors_supported
# bool function - getter of the terminal color support
# if true, then this code defines global color constants


tput_colors_supported ()
{
    command -v tput && tput bold && [ "$(tput colors)" -ge 8 ]
} > /dev/null 2>&1


if tput_colors_supported; then

    # tput special sequences
    number_of_colors=$(tput colors)
    color_reset=$(tput sgr0)
    bold_text=$(tput bold)

    # definitions of basic colors with bold test
    color_red=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 1)
    color_green=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 2)
    color_yellow=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 3)
    color_blue=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 4)
    color_magenta=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 5)
    color_cyan=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 6)
    color_white=${bold_text}$(tput setaf 7)

else

    number_of_colors=0; color_reset=; bold_text=; color_red=; color_green=; color_yellow=; color_blue=; color_magenta=; color_cyan=; color_white=

fi
```

- I would like to pinpoint **determining the number of colors available**:

  > ```
  > [ "$(tput colors)" -ge 8 ]
  > ```
- I was however puzzled by some older articles reporting that **`tput colors` returns a bad number on their systems**, so just be aware of it.
- Additionally, notice that **I redirected all output from the function to the *black hole* without using `exec`**. I had some problems with it ever since, I recommend to avoid it, if possible.
- Plus, note that I **removed the `readonly` keyword, as it can cause problems when re-sourcing** this file.
- Finally, if you are curious as to why I define all of the **empty variables in the `else`, that is because I use `set -u`** in the main script.

---

## The main functions

### File `func-print_error_and_exit_script`

```sh
#!/bin/sh


### REQUIREMENTS
# func-color_support

. /path/to/func-color_support


### METHODS

## print_error
# prints custom heading and error message without exiting the script; in color, if available

## print_error_and_exit_script
# direcly uses print_error, but this one exits the script with customizable exit code (optional 3rd argument)


print_error ()
# expected arguments:
# $1 = error heading (string)
# $2 = error message (string)
{
    # check if exactly 2 non-empty arguments have been passed
    # if not, print out an input check error without colors
    if [ $# -ne 2 ] || [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
        # $1 and $2 are to be shown literally in this message
        # link to wiki: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2016
        # shellcheck disable=SC2016
        printf 'print_error() input check\n\nWrong number or empty arguments have been passed to the function: %s\n\nExpected the following 2:\n$1 - error heading\n$2 - error message\n' $#
        return 1
    fi

    error_heading=$1
    error_message=$2

    printf '%b\n\n%b\n\n%b\n' \
        "Error heading: ${color_yellow}${error_heading}${color_reset}" \
        "Error message: ${error_message}" \
        "${color_red}Fatal error occurred.${color_reset}"
} >&2


print_error_and_exit_script ()
# expected arguments:
# $1 = error heading (string)
# $2 = error message (string)
# $3 = return code (number) - optional, if not given, 1 is used
{
    # check if 2 (or 3) non-empty arguments have been passed
    # if not, print out an input check error without colors
    if { [ $# -ne 2 ] && [ $# -ne 3 ]; } || [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
        # $1, $2, $3 are to be shown literally in this message
        # link to wiki: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2016
        # shellcheck disable=SC2016
        printf 'print_error_and_exit_script() input check\n\nWrong number or empty arguments have been passed to the function: %s\n\nExpected the following 2 or 3:\n$1 - error heading (string)\n$2 - error message (string)\n$3 - return code (number) - optional, if not given, 1 is used\n' $#
        return 1
    fi

    if [ $# -eq 2 ] || [ -z "$3" ]; then
        return_code=1
    elif [ -n "$3" ] && ! [ "$3" -eq "$3" ] 2> /dev/null; then
        printf 'print_error_and_exit_script() input check\n\nThird argument is expected to be a return code, i.e. a number.\nBut something else was passed instead: %s\n' "$3"
        return 1
    else
        return_code=$3
    fi

    print_error "$1" "$2"

    exit "$return_code"

} >&2
```

- Again, as explained above, **I avoided `exec`**, and redirected both functions' output with `>&2`.
- Considering **my need sometimes to only print error and not exit script**, the job has been divided into two functions:

  - `print_error`: **prints custom heading and error message without exiting the script**; in color, if available
  - `print_error_and_exit_script`: direcly uses print_error, but **this one exits the script with customizable exit code (optional 3rd argument)**

---

### Visual example

This is just so you see it in action, `sudoedit_run` is a function utilizing `print_error`.

[image: sudoedit_run--errors]