# Lock file and interrupt signals in POSIX shell script running indefinitely

Tags: error-handling, sh, posix

This script is running indefinitely as the Linux background process.

I have put an enormous effort to make this **POSIX** shell script containing an **infinite loop** shut down tidily along with the operating system (TERM signal) and by me sending it a HUP signal.

Ok, we don't call it *exception-handling*, but I didn't find any other suitable tag for it. Also did not find an appropriate tag for the script's termination.

We have reviewed two big pieces of the puzzle already, so I cut it out.

---

```sh
readonly script_one_instance_lockfile="${HOME}/.PROGRAM/$(basename "${0}").lock"

# this is long and not relevant to this question, it does as its name says
# you can find a review on it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204828/104270
print_error_and_exit() { ... }

is_number()
{
    [ "${1}" -eq "${1}" ] 2> /dev/null
}

# purpose is clear, i.e. to clean up some temp, lock files
# which were created during script execution and should not be left in place
cleanup_on_exit()
{
    [ -f "${script_one_instance_lockfile}" ] && rm "${script_one_instance_lockfile}"
}

# this function is merely for future expansions of the script
# it might very well be different from cleanup_on_exit
cleanup_on_signal()
{
    cleanup_on_exit
}

# here we define a generic function to handle signals
# treat them as errors with appropriate messages
# example calls:
#    kill -15   this_script_name    # POSIX; all shells compatible
#    kill -TERM this_script_name    # Bash and alike; newer shells
signal_handler_generic()
# expected arguments:
# $1 = signal code
{
    # check if exactly one argument has been passed
    [ "${#}" -eq 1 ] || print_error_and_exit "signal_handler_generic()" "Exactly one argument has not been passed!\\n\\tPassed: ${*}"

    # check if the argument is a number
    is_number "${1}" || print_error_and_exit "signal_handler_generic()" "The argument is not a number!\\n\\Signal code expected.\\n\\tPassed: ${1}"

    number_argument=${1}
    signal_code=${number_argument}
    case "${number_argument}" in
        1 ) signal_human_friendly='HUP'  ;;
        2 ) signal_human_friendly='INT'  ;;
        3 ) signal_human_friendly='QUIT' ;;
        6 ) signal_human_friendly='ABRT' ;;
        15) signal_human_friendly='TERM' ;;
        * ) signal_human_friendly=''     ;;
    esac

    if [ "${signal_human_friendly}" = "" ]
    then
        print_error_and_exit "signal_handler_generic()" "Given number code (${signal_code}) does not correspond to supported signal codes."
    else
        # tidy up any temp or lock files created along the way
        cleanup_on_signal
        # print human friendly and number signal code that has been caught
        print_error_and_exit "\\ntrap()" "Caught ${signal_human_friendly} termination signal ${signal_code}.\\n\\tClean-up finished. Exiting. Bye!"
    fi
}

# use the above function for signal handling;
# note that the SIG* constants are undefined in POSIX,
# and numbers are to be used for the signals instead
trap 'signal_handler_generic 1' 1
trap 'signal_handler_generic 2' 2
trap 'signal_handler_generic 3' 3
trap 'signal_handler_generic 6' 6
trap 'signal_handler_generic 15' 15

# this is long and not relevant to this question, it does as its name says
# you can find a review on it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/213156/104270
is_java_program_running() { ... }

####################
### MAIN PROGRAM ###
####################

if [ -f "${script_one_instance_lockfile}" ]
then
    # if one instance of this script is already running, quit to shell
    print_error_and_exit "\\nmain()" "One instance of this script should already be running.\\n\\tLock file: ${script_one_instance_lockfile}\\n\\tMore than one instance is not allowed. Exiting."
else
    # create a .lock file for one instance handling
    touch "${script_one_instance_lockfile}"
fi

# keep the PROGRAM alive forever, check in 5 seconds interval
while true
do
    sleep 5s

    if ! is_java_program_running "${PROGRAM_java_process_identifier}"
    then
        my_date_time=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)
        printf '%s  %s\n' "${my_date_time}" "(re-)starting PROGRAM"
        ( /full/path/to/program > /dev/null 2>&1 & )
    fi
done

# ordinary scripts don't have infinite loops
# this code shall be unreachable, but it is good to have it here since I will be
# copying / reusing the script and I would definitely forget on this
cleanup_on_exit
```

Comment: Have you actually found a Unix or `kill` that doesn't deal with signal names?  [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) says that POSIX does define those names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simplify with `case`, and eliminate a conditional

Instead of this:

> ```
> case "${number_argument}" in
>     1 ) signal_human_friendly='HUP'  ;;
>     2 ) signal_human_friendly='INT'  ;;
>     3 ) signal_human_friendly='QUIT' ;;
>     6 ) signal_human_friendly='ABRT' ;;
>     15) signal_human_friendly='TERM' ;;
>     * ) signal_human_friendly=''     ;;
> esac
>
> if [ "${signal_human_friendly}" = "" ]
> then
>     print_error_and_exit "..."
> else
>     # tidy up ...
> fi
> ```

I suggest to move the `print_error_and_exit` in the `case`,
and then you can eliminate the conditional that follows,
and "flatten" the code:

```
case "${number_argument}" in
    1 ) signal_human_friendly='HUP'  ;;
    2 ) signal_human_friendly='INT'  ;;
    3 ) signal_human_friendly='QUIT' ;;
    6 ) signal_human_friendly='ABRT' ;;
    15) signal_human_friendly='TERM' ;;
    * ) print_error_and_exit "..." ;;
esac

# tidy up ...
```

#### Eliminate a low-value conditional statement

Instead of this:

> ```
> [ -f "${script_one_instance_lockfile}" ] && rm "${script_one_instance_lockfile}"
> ```

Why not simply:

```
rm -f "${script_one_instance_lockfile}"
```

#### Sharpen error messages

Instead of "Exactly one argument has not been passed! [...] Passed: ...",

I would write "Expected one argument. Received: ...".

Comment: `rm -f` does produce an error message for `ENOENT`, so the test isn't *completely* useless.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts intended to be executable should have a shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

The repetitive calls to `trap` could be replaced by a loop:

```
for i in 1 2 3 6 15
do trap "signal_handler_generic $i" $i
done
```

(Note: if using Shellcheck, you may need `# shellcheck disable=SC2064`: we must not use single-quotes here, as it would make no sense to defer the expansion of `$i`).

With some small changes, we could trap the signals by name (the names *are* specified in POSIX, contrary to the code comment), and not need the conversion from number in the handler.

Consider letting `SIGHUP` mean "reload configuration" as is conventional in daemons.

I think the name `script_one_instance_lockfile` is possibly over-long.  As it's the only lock file we use, we could call it simply `lockfile` and get more of our lines down to a reasonable length.

There's no need to capture the output of `date` if the only thing we do with it is to immediately print it:

```
    date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S  (re-)starting PROGRAM'
```

Use `test -e` (or `[ -e`) to test for existence, where the file type is irrelevant.  Also consider using a pidfile, so that after unclean shutdown and recovery, invocation isn't inhibited.  BTW, is it intentional that the lockfile is in (per-user) `$HOME`, rather than per-machine in some temporary filesystem (e.g. `/run` on Linux)?

Comment: Thank you Toby for clearing some of the things I was unsure of. I just had to add that comment.